# Trying to disable a gesture tooltip occuring when i 'flick' in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, tooltip, gesture

there is some default functionality on a WPF application that i would like to disable. Whenever i make a 'flick' gesture, by touch down and doing a quick drag and release, i get a popup/tooltip appearing briefly showing: "Drag Down", "Drag Up", "Forward" and "Back", for flick Up, down, left, and right respectively. These "Tooltips" have 2 different icons, and can be reproduced when i make a new empty WPF project.

I have tried to disable this by overriding some of the seemingly relevant methods and setting the event to handled, but i cant seem to find a way to stop this from happening. If you know a solution, i would be grateful.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is just flick recognition in the OS itself. Check your control panel / system tray.
edit: specifically, the "Pen and Touch" settings in the control panel

Answer (score 0):

I think you can disable the flick recognition by setting `Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled="False"`. See [Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylus.isflicksenabled(v=vs.110).aspx).